# Is "allied topics" a term reserved for the Academia?

Tags: phrases

Context: I recently left a comment on Area51 telling a user that their question is *more suitable for X.SE since [that site] is focused on X and **allied topics***.

I'm sure I heard someone use that phrase during a public speaking session, but, according to Google, the only people that use it seem to be the Annual *ASMS Conference on Mass Spectrometry and Allied Topics*.

**Q.** Is that phrase considered valid, every-day English, or is it perhaps laden with Academick Connotations?

N.B. I could've used *related topics* but for some reason I like *allied* best.

Comment: I think you're right that it's mostly used in scholarly contexts.

Comment: Not that it would be wrong in ordinary writing. It's certainly understandable.

Comment: There's nothing wrong using with *allied topics* in everyday speech or writing, though it's not something you'll often hear in casual or informal conversations.

Comment: Why would you consider *allied* a better fit in the context?

Comment: See also: [writers.se] and [academia.se]

Comment: @Kris I don't know! It sounded better in my head at the time :)

Comment: Check the definitions of both in a good dictionary, and usage from literature, though gut feeling could be more correct at times with things like this.

Comment: Sounds decidedly odd to me, like the topics are making some kind of military alliance. Perhaps because _related topics_ is such a fixed phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is “allied topics” a term reserved for the academia?

No.

- Firstly, the phrase happens to be rare, about 2,340 results on Google
  Search, against about 6,050,000 results for *related topic*.
- Secondly, some taxonomical methods use the phrase pair *Main Topic*
  and *Allied Topic(s)*, which necessitates the use of the phrase, at
  least in some academic writing.

I suggest treating the word pair as a **phrase,** not a **term,** except when used as in 'Secondly' above.